# Why is my responsive design working when I use the mobile device tool, but if I decrease the browser itself, it's not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

When I use the `toggle device tool` on the `Inspect tools` of my browser, my responsive design works as expected, but if I instead just minimize the browser, then it's not working. Is this a bug?

I am using JavaScript to detect the screen size. This is the function:

```
if(window.screen.availWidth > 1024 && window.screen.availWidth < 1200) { 
 ...
} else if(window.screen.availWidth > 1200) { 

... 

}
```

I have noticed that the first condition `window.screen.availWidth > 1024 && window.screen.availWidth < 1200` is not met when I shrink/enlarge the browser itself, but it's met, as it should be, when I use the mobile tool from the inspect tools.

This is the mobile tool I am referring to:

[image]

Is this a bug, or is it related to the `availWidth` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.screen.availWidth` returns the width of the device screen, not the browser screen. When you use the mobile tool, the browser emulates a mobile device and hence the webpage thinks that the screen is of a mobile, regardless of the browser size. However, when `window.screen.availWidth` takes the width of the screen (your monitor) and it does not take the size of the browser window.

You might want to take a look at the `window.innerWidth` property instead.

Comment: [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) is probably a better bet than `innerWidth`.

Comment: @Quentin How does it work? Can I just replace `window.screen.availWidth` with `window.screen.matchMedia`?

Comment: @user21616350 Consider [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_matchmedia.asp) from W3Schools

Comment: @user21616350 — No. See the documentation I linked to.